# influxdb select query integer formatting

Tags: format, influxdb

I have an influx table with the volumes of bytes per time. I would like to make a select through GET-request to get the last value:

```
curl -u 'user:pass' -G 'https://influx/query?db=traffic&pretty=false' --data-urlencode "db=mydb" --data-urlencode "q=SELECT last(sum) FROM traffic WHERE zone='main'"
```

Select works but instead of 6 433 336 Bytes it returns 6.433336e+06 which is not convenient and sometimes not precise enough for me. How can I get this integer as is without conversion to the scientific format?

Comment: I'd open [a feature request](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/new) requesting this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to return this value not in scientific notation.

Comment: would this be added as a new feature in the future?

Comment: If a feature request gets opened and appropriately prioritized.

Comment: added feature request for tracking https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/8077